# Access min/max values for a Highcharts series: afterSetExtremes does not fire

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Highcharts has an event for [`afterSetExtremes`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes):

> As opposed to the setExtremes event, this event fires after the final min and max values are computed and corrected for minRange.

Except, it only fires if you specifically call `setExtremes` somewhere in your code.

I need to access the computed min and max values for a series. Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: You need min and max for the Series? Or for the Axis? For the series, just loop through your points and find min/max. For the Axis, call: `chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes()`. The same applies for the xAxes.

Comment: For the axes. getExtremes doesn't work - they are still NaN/null at the time of calling it. Hence the need for an event trigger that works.

Comment: Interesting - maybe your charts isn't initialized, like answer below? Or you don't have any data on the chart? Anyway, see [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes) - demo works fine.

Comment: `Except, it only fires if you specifically call setExtremes somewhere in your code.` - that is incorrect. `afterSetExtremes` also fires when the user zooms in somewhere else - see the [async loading example](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call the [`axis.getExtremes()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.getExtremes) to get the desired information.
As you mentioned in your comment the values are `null/NaN`, you can use the chart [`load`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.events.load) event handler if you want the values immediately on load

```
Highcharts.StockChart(chartingOptions,function(){
    var extremes=this.xAxis[0].getExtremes();
    alert('Min: ' + extremes.min + ', Max: ' + extremes.max 
          + ', dataMin: ' + extremes.dataMin + ', dataMax: ' + extremes.dataMax 
          + ', userMin: ' + extremes.userMin + ', userMax: ' + extremes.userMax);

});
```

[demo @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/k3aL92n6/)